# Hibernate projection property whole object

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I have a case like this:
`Class Foo` with two children (`A` and `B`), each being `Objects`.
In Hibernate, if I want to return only a list of the children, I would use projections on my criteria:

```
criteria.setProjection(Projections.property("A"));
```

This gives me a list of `A objects`, but they are all `lazy` loaded. As soon as I try to access anything other than the `id`, obviously things go wrong.
My `SQL` query indeed shows it:

```
select A from Foo ...
```

Logically, only my id is filled in, and not the rest of my properties. How do I solve this problem so I get a list of `A objects` that have everything filled in?
I tried this:

```
criteria.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(A.class));
```

but without success.

Comment: is it necessary to use criteria??

Comment: Actually not? I have thought about doing this with a hibernate query :).

Answer (score 1):

if you use hql it would be more efficient:

```
String hql = "SELECT f.A FROM Foo f";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
List results = query.list();
```

Using criteria I would have use this code

```
    Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Foo.class); 
    ProjectionList proList = Projections.projectionList();      
    proList.add(Projections.property("A"));
    crit.setProjection(proList);
    List As= crit.list();
```

or this block

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Foo.class);
crit.createAlias("A","a").setProjection(Projections.property("a"));
List As= crit.list();
```

Comment: I solved the problem like this indeed. I just wondered if it was possible with Criteria.